# How do I mute a track in this Arrangement view for playback of another track in Clip view?

Tags: ableton-live, mute

[[image: [1]]

Is it possible to mute vocal tracks to listen to only instruments while composing in Clip view?

Comment: You should add an Ableton tag. Also, I am puzzled there is no mute button, therefore, I follow the question.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the trial version come with a manual? Try the Help menu.

Quote from version 9 manual

> To mute the track's output, turn off the Track Activator switch.

The page where this is from, has a picture showing what the Track Activator switch is.

Answer (score 2):

and good question!

What might be confusing here is that there isn't a "mute button" per se, rather like piiperi Reinstate Monica pointed out, there are "activator" switches on each track that control whether that track is audible:

[image: Ableton Track Activator Example Image]

Note that a slight distinction should be made here: Just because the track isn't audible, doesn't mean it isn't being played. This comes into play with things like sidechaining ghost notes.

I should also point out, there is no "clip view" in Ableton -- there's Session View and Arrangement View. You're in Arrangement View. I point out this distinction because you can work with clips in both modes, and in fact, you can deactivate clips individually from deactivating a while track as well. (Shortcut is 0 (zero) when you have the clip selected)

I would also agree with piiperi Reinstate Monica that you should read through the manual. There's a lot of useful info in there that you might not think you would need! Best of luck!